# Regex to search and replace... unwrap code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hoping someone can help me. I'm trying to do a rather large refactor and hoping regex can come to my rescue. Given this block of code/text:

```
import { Something } from '../../donotmatter';
import { wrapperFunction } from '../../utils';

export const things = {
  Things: {
    ThingA: wrapperFunction((foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    }),
    ThingB: wrapperFunction((foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    }),
    ThingC: wrapperFunction((foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    }),
  },
  Stuff: {
    StuffA: wrapperFunction((foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    }),
    StuffB: wrapperFunction((foo: string, bar: object) => {
      const data = {
        stats: "all",
        countries: "some",
      };
      return Something.other("aa");
    }),
    StuffC: wrapperFunction((foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    }),
  },
};
```

I'm trying to "unwrap" by removing the `wrapperFunction` wrapper. This is across hundreds of files.

Visual Studio Code's regex find/replace seems a little different than I expect? I don't know. Hoping someone can help.

For completeness, this would be the end result:

```
import { Something } from '../../donotmatter';
import { wrapperFunction } from '../../utils';

export const things = {
  Things: {
    ThingA: (foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    },
    ThingB: (foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    },
    ThingC: (foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    },
  },
  Stuff: {
    StuffA: (foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    },
    StuffB: (foo: string, bar: object) => {
      const data = {
        stats: "all",
        countries: "some",
      };
      return Something.other("aa");
    },
    StuffC: (foo: string, bar: object) => {
      return Something.other("aa");
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: regex can't count brackets and braces, write a Python/JavaScript/... script that parses the file and finds the wrapper function and keeps count of `{}` and remove the wrapper, then with a `find . -name "*.js" | xargs -I {} python script.py {}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just search for : `(?<=: )\b.*\b\((?=\()|(?<=\})\)(?=,)`

and replace with nothing.

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ub9Mbu/1)

Or search for:

`(?<=: )\b.*\b\((?=\()|(^\s*\})\)(?=,$)`

Replace: `$1`

which ensures that

`}),` is the only text on that line if `}),` might occur where you don't want to change it.

[regex101 demo2](https://regex101.com/r/Wb1Eya/1)

Comment: the content of the function can have any complexity so there will be cases it will not handle or handle incorrect

Comment: Like most such regex's it does depend on the regularity of the input to avoid being horrendous.  The user should know.  It works for the given input.